# Norm-controlled inverses vs uniform openness of multiplication

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, banach-algebras

Let $A$ be a unital commutative Banach algebra and let $\hat{a}\in C(\Phi_A)$ be the Gelfand transform of an element $a\in A$. The algebra $A$ has *norm-controlled inverses*, whenever there exists a function $h\colon [0,\infty)^2\to [0,\infty)$ so that 
$$\|a^{-1}\| \leqslant h(\|a\|, \|\widehat{a^{-1}}\|_\infty)$$
for any invertible element $a\in A$. Many naturally arising cBas have this property, however, $A=\ell_1(\mathbb Z)$ (with convolution) is a notable example of a Banach algebra that fails to have norm-controlled inverses (see Nikolski's paper). Hence my question:

I wonder if there is any relation between norm-controlled inverse and [having uniformly open multiplication](https://mathoverflow.net/q/270616/15129). It is known that $\ell_1(\mathbb Z)$ does not have uniformly open convolution, however, ${\rm BV}[0,1]$ does have norm-controlled inverses, yet the (pointwise) product is not uniformly open (see Kowalczyk–Turowska).

> Suppose that $A$ is a unital semi-simple commutative Banach algebra that has uniformly open multiplication. Does it have norm-controlled inverses?

Some examples of (complex) Banach algebras that have uniformly open multiplication:

- $C(X)$ for a compact, zero-dimensional Hausdorff space (Komisarski in the real case but the proof works also for the complex scalars) and $C[0,1]$ (Behrends, unpublished in the uniformly open case). I have a proof that extends this to all $C(X)$ for $X$ metric and having covering dimension 1. When $\dim X \geqslant 2$, $C(X)$ fails to have open multiplication.
- $C^1[0,1]$ does have norm-controlled inverses, and it seems I can prove it has uniformly open multiplication too.

References:

- A. Komisarski, A connection between multiplication in $C(X)$ and the dimension of $X$, *Fund. Math*. **189** (2) (2006), 149–154.
- S. Kowalczyk, M. Turowska, Multiplication in the space of functions of bounded variation. *J. Math. Anal. Appl.*, **472** (2019), 696–704.
- N. Nikolski, In search of the invisible spectrum. *Ann. Inst. Fourier (Grenoble)*, **49** (1999), 1925–1998.

Comment: Hi Tomek, could you remind us of some examples which are known to have uniformly open multiplication? My understanding, after a very quick look at your paper with Szymon, is that C(K) need not have this property, but does have this property if K is zero-dimensional and compact. What happens for uniform algebras, or algebras such as C^1[0,1]?

Comment: @YemonChoi, sure, added. As for other uniform algebras than $C^1[0,1]$ I am not sure. A necessary condition for openness is that the maximal ideal space is (at most) one-dimensional.